# ошибка добавление в MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

парсю информацию с каналов телеграм, и необходимо добавить в базу данных MySQL спарсенные значения.
Проблема возникает с этой строчкой:

```
Luna Lovers'
```

Как ее добавить правильно?

```
Ошибка: 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

SQL

```
    INSERT INTO entity(address, name, count_subscribers, description, count_photos, count_videos, count_audio,
count_shared_links, count_voice, type, pinned_message_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

**UPDATE:**

Данные

```
(5, "I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean about 10 billion dollars?", None, 1, 'Christine ', '2019-01-10', '10:21:38')
```

SQL запрос:

```
UPDATE entity SET message_type = %s, message = %s, shared_link = %s
WHERE id_entity = %s and username = %s and post_date = %s and message_time = %s LIMIT 1
```

Ошибка:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id_entity = 1 and username = 'Christine ?' and post_date = '2019-01-10' and mess' at line 1
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: @strawdog прочитал, так и не понял. У меня кодировка utf-8_general, мне необходимо к другой кодировке чтоль приравнивать?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, нужно изменить кодировку таблиц с utf8mb4_general_ci на utf8mb4.

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

> проблема в том, что в базе данных Майэскуэль первые реализации УТФ-8 были кривыми и не умели хранить нужные для эмодзей четырёхбайтные символы. А когда научились, для обратной совместимости это стало называться «кодировкой» utf8mb4
>   [Пост Бирмана](https://ilyabirman.ru/meanwhile/all/aegea-2-8-beta/)

Comment: так у меня кодировка utf8_general_ci. У нее тоже проблемы такие?

Comment: Именно про utf8_general_ci и идет речь: "в базе данных Майэскуэль первые реализации УТФ-8 были кривыми и не умели хранить нужные для эмодзей четырёхбайтные символы"

Comment: select срабатывает нормально, но при попытке update со строкой выкидывает ошибку, добавил в обновление